# Entity Framework updates with wrong values after insert

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-6

This issue is discovered because I have an object with a field calculated off the ID, which contains the ID as part of it with a prefix and a checksum digit.  It is a requirement that these calculated values are unique, but they also cannot be random, so this seemed the best way to do it.

The code in question looks like this:

```
entity = new Entity() { /* values */ };
context.SaveChanges(); //generate the ID field
entity.CALCULATED_FIELD = CalculateField(prefix, entity.ID);
```

This works just fine in 99% of cases, but occasionally we get a value in the database which looks like:

```
ID: 1234
CALCULATED_FIELD : prefix000{1233}8
EXPECTED: prefix000{1234}3
```

With the parts in the braces being calculated from the ID column.

The fact that the calculated field is incorrect is bad enough, but the implication is that upon doing a savechanges, there is no guarantee that the row returned to Entity Framework is the one which was originally worked on!  I am looking into using a stored procedure on insert in order to fix the generated field problem, but in the long run we're going to have lots of bad data if we keep working on the wrong rows.

When I told entity framework to map the table to stored procedures it generated the following boilerplate code:

```
INSERT [dbo].[tableName](fields...)
VALUES(values...)

DECLARE @ID int
SELECT @ID = [ID]
FROM [dbo].[tableName]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [ID] = scope_identity()

SELECT t0.[ID]
FROM [dbo].[tableName] as t0
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND t0.[ID] = @ID
```

The best idea I can come up with is that an extra insert could occur before scope_identity() is called.  We are migrating this system from using stored procedures where we used @@IDENTITY in place instead, could there be a difference there?

EDIT: CalculateField:

```
    public static string CalculateField(string prefix, int ID)
    {
        var calculated = prefix.PadRight(17 - ID.ToString().Length)
            .Replace(" ", "0") + ID.ToString();
        var multiplier = 3;
        var sum = 0;
        foreach (char c in calculated.ToCharArray().Reverse())
        {
            sum += multiplier * int.Parse(c.ToString());
            multiplier = 4 - multiplier;
        }
        if (sum % 10 == 0) { return calculated + "0"; }
        return calculated + (10 - (sum % 10)).ToString();
    }
```

UPDATE: Changing the called method from static to an instance method and only running it later after additional changed were made instead of straight after creation appears to have solved the problem, for reasons I can't comprehend.  I'm leaving the question open for now since I don't yet have a large enough sample to be completely sure the problem is resolved, and also because I have no explanation for what really changed.

Comment: Where is the code for `CalculateField`? And no I dont think EF has a bug that does not return the correct id.